# Can iPhone app play audio over the top of iTunes?

Tags: ios, itunes, avaudiosession

Can an iPhone app play/overlay an audio source over the top of the iTunes app?

Ie. Can a user have a song playing in the iTunes app whilst my app plays additional audio simultaneously?

Can expand further if required.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html), in section “Choosing the Best Category”, there is:

> `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` or the equivalent `kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound`
>
> Use this category for an application that plays sounds that add polish or interest but are not essential to the application’s use. Using this category, your audio is silenced by the Ring/Silent switch and when the screen locks.
>
> This category allows audio from the iPod, Safari, and other built-in applications to play while your application is playing audio. You could, for example, use this category for an application that provides a virtual musical instrument that a user plays along to iPod audio.

I think this is what you're looking for.